# How to deserialize a map into a vector of a custom struct, with a field matching the key?

Tags: rust, yaml, deserialization, serde

Given a yaml with a map of items,

```yaml
items:
  item1:
    uid: ab1234
    foo: bar
  item2:
    uid: cd5678
    foo: baz
```

how can I parse it with serde into a `Vec<Item>` with a new field, "name", generated from the key of the original map,

```rust
struct Item {
  name: String,  // to be populated by the key (item1, item2)
  uid: String,
  foo: String,
}
```

I'm trying to get the following code ([rustexplorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)) to work, which currently errors out with `Err(Error("items: invalid type: map, expected a sequence", line: 3, column: 3))`.

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.193"
serde_derive = "1.0.193"
serde_yaml = "0.9.27"
*/

use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::vec::Vec;


#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Item {
  name: String,
  uid: String,
  foo: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Schema {
    items: Vec<Item>,
}

fn main() {
    let input = r###"
items:
  item1:
    uid: ab1234
    foo: bar
  item2:
    uid: cd5678
    foo: baz
"###;

    let items = serde_yaml::from_str::<Schema>(input);
    println!("{:?}", items);
}
```

Comment: Seems doable with [`serde_as`](https://github.com/jonasbb/serde_with/issues/32) but not sure how.

Comment: ot: You can import `serde_derive` through the main `serde` crate with the feature `derive` and replace `serde_derive` with just `serde`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`serde_with`](https://docs.rs/serde_with) has something for exactly that: [`KeyValueMap`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/struct.KeyValueMap.html):

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_with::{serde_as, KeyValueMap};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Item {
    #[serde(rename = "$key$")]
    name: String,
    uid: String,
    foo: String,
}

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Schema {
    #[serde_as(as = "KeyValueMap<_>")]
    items: Vec<Item>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without intermediate allocations using a custom deserializer and a [`Visitor`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.Visitor.html):

```
use serde::Deserializer;
use serde::de::MapAccess;
use serde::de::Visitor;
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::fmt;
use std::vec::Vec;


#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Item {
  name: String,
  uid: String,
  foo: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Schema {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_items")]
    items: Vec<Item>,
}

fn deserialize_items<'de, D> (deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<Item>, D::Error>
where D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    struct ItemsVisitor;

    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for ItemsVisitor
    {
        type Value = Vec<Item>;

        fn expecting (&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("an items map")
        }
        
        fn visit_map<M> (self, mut map: M) -> Result<Vec<Item>, M::Error>
        where M: MapAccess<'de>,
        {
            #[derive(Deserialize)]
            struct ItemFields {
                uid: String,
                foo: String,
            }

            let mut result = vec![];
            while let Some ((name, fields)) = map.next_entry::<_, ItemFields>()? {
                result.push (Item { name, uid: fields.uid, foo: fields.foo });
            }
            Ok (result)
        }
    }
    
    deserializer.deserialize_map (ItemsVisitor)
}

fn main() {
    let input = r###"
items:
  item1:
    uid: ab1234
    foo: bar
  item2:
    uid: cd5678
    foo: baz
"###;

    let items = serde_yaml::from_str::<Schema>(input);
    println!("{:?}", items);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0498db49512f822bdf82ce100896afdc)

See also: https://serde.rs/stream-array.html

Answer (score 1):

While certainly not the cleanest solution to this problem, you could combine the `tuple_vec_map` crate and a custom deserialization function:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Schema {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "vec_item")]
    items: Vec<Item>,
}

fn vec_item<'de, D>(de: D) -> Result<Vec<Item>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    struct ItemSerde {
        uid: String,
        foo: String,
    }
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    #[serde(transparent)]
    struct SchemaSerde(#[serde(with = "tuple_vec_map")] Vec<(String, ItemSerde)>);

    let SchemaSerde(items) = Deserialize::deserialize(de)?;
    Ok(items
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(name, ItemSerde { uid, foo })| Item { name, uid, foo })
        .collect())
}
```

[Explorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)

Answer (score 1):

You could read into a temporary map of `String` -> `RawItem` (item without name), and transform that into the structure you need:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Schema {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_schema_items")]
    items: Vec<Item>,
}

fn deserialize_schema_items<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<Vec<Item>, D::Error> {
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    struct RawItem {
        uid: String,
        foo: String,
    }
    let raw_items: IndexMap<String, RawItem> = Deserialize::deserialize(d)?;
    let items = raw_items
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(name, raw_item)| Item {
            name,
            uid: raw_item.uid,
            foo: raw_item.foo,
        })
        .collect();
    Ok(items)
}
```

The above code uses `indexmap::IndexMap` to preserve order. If you don't care about order, you can use `HashMap` instead. If you opt for `IndexMap`, note that you'll need to turn on the `serde` feature of the `indexmap` crate.